# Shilft select multiple checkboxes in a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I found a solution to select a single range of checkboxes in table created by JsGrid.

```
    $(document).on('click', '[type = checkbox]' , function(e) {
        if (e.shiftKey) {
            var first = $("#jsGrid input[type='checkbox']:checked").first().parent().parent().index(),
            last = $("#jsGrid input[type='checkbox']:checked").last().parent().parent().index();

        for (var i = first; i < last; i++) {
            $("#jsGrid").find("tbody tr index").eq(i).children().first().find("input[type='checkbox']").prop("checked", true);

            $("#jsGrid .jsgrid-grid-body tbody tr").eq(i).find("input[type='checkbox']").prop("checked", true)
            }
        }
    });
```

The problem with this solution is that is only allows for a single range of checkboxes.

To add multiple ranges, I can set the bottom of the range to the current row index with

```
last = $(this).parent().parent().index();
```

Now I would like to find the row index of the row with next row above that has a selected checkbox.

I would think it should be a variant of the code below.

```
first = $(this).prevUntil(':checkbox', 'checked').parent().parent().index();  // -1
```

I can't get this to work.
Or this

```
 first = $(this).parent().parent().prevUntil(':checkbox', 'checked').index();  // -1
```

HTML

```
<tbody>
  <tr class="jsgrid-row">
   <td>1</td>
   <td><input type="checkbox" rel="898"></td>
   <td>02/27/2019</td>
   <td>19122-37</td>
   <td>SMITH</td>  
 </tr>
 <tr class="jsgrid-alt-row">
  <td>1</td>
  <td><input type="checkbox" rel="898"></td>
  <td>02/27/2019</td>
  <td>19122-37</td>
  <td>SMITH</td>  
 </tr>
 <tr class="jsgrid-row">
  <td>1</td>
  <td><input type="checkbox" rel="898"></td>
  <td>02/27/2019</td>
  <td>19122-37</td>
  <td>SMITH</td>  
 </tr>
 <tr class="jsgrid-alt-row">
  <td>1</td>
  <td><input type="checkbox" rel="898"></td>
  <td>02/27/2019</td>
  <td>19122-37</td>
  <td>SMITH</td>  
 </tr>  
</tbody>
```

Thanks!

[image: shift select]

Comment: While we talk here about **find** the element .. It will be better to show your **rendered** Html code not the js code while you don't have any issue with js

Comment: I added the rendered html

Comment: So you need to get all the row indexs which has a checked checkbox? or all the rows has checked checkboxes before the clicked one?? or just check the previous row it has a checked checkbox or not?

Comment: No. I want to find a single index of the closest checked box above in the table of the box that is shift-selected. The point of this to check all checkbox between 2 (first and last) boxes when I shift-select the lower box. I thought I could use prevUntil to traverse the table up over the unchecked boxes until it get the next checked one.

Comment: Caldera500 .. answer updated with the `prevUntil()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[1]** <sup>**What I understand is:** When checked the last checkbox get the nearest previous row which has checked checkbox</sup>

```js
$('input[type="checkbox"]:last').on('change' , function(){
  if(this.checked){
    var ThisRowIndex = $(this).closest('tr').index();
    $($('table tr:lt('+ (ThisRowIndex) +')').get().reverse()).filter(function(){
      return $(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length;
    }).each(function(){
      console.log('This Nearst Row Index: '+ $(this).index() + ' Has checked checkbox');
      return false;
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="jsgrid-row">
     <td>1</td>
     <td><input type="checkbox" value="100" rel="898"/></td>
     <td>02/27/2019</td>
     <td>19122-37</td>
     <td>SMITH</td>  
   </tr>
   <tr class="jsgrid-alt-row">
    <td>1</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" rel="898"/></td>
    <td>02/27/2019</td>
    <td>19122-37</td>
    <td>SMITH</td>  
   </tr>
   <tr class="jsgrid-row">
    <td>1</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" rel="898"/></td>
    <td>02/27/2019</td>
    <td>19122-37</td>
    <td>SMITH</td>  
   </tr>
   <tr class="jsgrid-alt-row">
    <td>1</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" rel="898"></td>
    <td>02/27/2019</td>
    <td>19122-37</td>
    <td>SMITH</td>  
   </tr>  
  </tbody>
</table>
```

<sup>**Explanation:**</sup>- with `checkbox` use `change` event.

```
if(this.checked){  // if this checkbox checked
   var ThisRowIndex = $(this).closest('tr').index();    // get the closest ow index when this checkbox checked
   $('table tr:lt('+ (ThisRowIndex) +')').filter(function(){  // use `lt()` to select the previous rows then filter them to check if there is a checked checkbox in each one or not
       return $(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length; //check if there is a checked checkbox in each one or not
   }).each(function(){  // loop through the rows which has checked checkbox
      console.log('This Row With Index: '+ $(this).index() + ' Has checked  checkbox'); // print the index of each row
   });
}
```

- For reverse you can use `$($('table tr:lt('+ (ThisRowIndex) +')').get().reverse())` .. see updated snippet
- `:last` for the last element
- `return false;` in `.each()` break the loop

> <sup>**Note** With the above piece of code you can do a lot of things
>   .. Just understand the idea of it and it will be very helpful for
>   you</sup>

---

**[2]** <sup>**And with `prevUntil()`** to get the indexes of the rows between index checked checkbox and the shift-select checkbox</sup>

```js
$('input[type="checkbox"]:last').on('change' , function(){
  if(this.checked){
    $(this).closest('tr').prevUntil('tr:has(input[type="checkbox"]:checked)').each(function(){
      console.log($(this).index());
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="jsgrid-row">
     <td>1</td>
     <td><input type="checkbox" value="100" rel="898"/></td>
     <td>02/27/2019</td>
     <td>19122-37</td>
     <td>SMITH</td>  
   </tr>
   <tr class="jsgrid-alt-row">
    <td>1</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" rel="898"/></td>
    <td>02/27/2019</td>
    <td>19122-37</td>
    <td>SMITH</td>  
   </tr>
   <tr class="jsgrid-row">
    <td>1</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" rel="898"/></td>
    <td>02/27/2019</td>
    <td>19122-37</td>
    <td>SMITH</td>  
   </tr>
   <tr class="jsgrid-alt-row">
    <td>1</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" rel="898"></td>
    <td>02/27/2019</td>
    <td>19122-37</td>
    <td>SMITH</td>  
   </tr>  
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Great. Thank You! Your answer helped me to refactor the code and avoid even dealing with row index. The code below will set the checkboxes.   $(this).children().find("input[type='checkbox']").prop("checked", true);

Comment: No need for `.children()` you can directly use `$(this).find` .. Have a great day :-) @Caldera500